# Reload in Python interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, reload

```
$ python
>>> import myapp
>>> reload(myapp)
<module 'myapp' from 'myapp.pyc'>
>>>
```

<kbd>ctrl+D</kbd>

```
$ python
>>> from myapp import *
>>> reload(myapp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myapp' is not defined
```

Why this behaves differently? How can I reload when using `from myapp import *`?

Comment: The reason I use *reload()* is because I change the source code of the module and test it and the reason I use *from myapp import* is because it saves me typing.

Comment: `reload` is to be used with a *lot* of caution. It behaves unexpected in many ways, the worst of which is that classes exist in many versions inside the VM, depending on whether you have old instances of reloaded classes hanging around. `reload` was removed from Python 3 for that reason. Often it's much easier to set up a small script setting up all the modules you need and then drop into a shell using `import code; code.interact(local=locals())`. The Python interpreter starts up really fast, so this is usually even faster then searching for `reload` in the readline history.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you for advice, but I can't imagine this without some example. If it's possible and you have time to write more about it, please put some example to an answer. Or I can create a new question based on your comment, if you're not against it.

Comment: I meant something like http://pastie.org/3844991. Instead of having a shell open and trying to reload stuff (which can't properly work), you can just reload the whole shell from scratch using that script. This also has the advantage of forcing you to explicitly setup the context you want to test, so you can reproduce everything you do and have the option to turn this into a unit test easily later on.

Comment: @NiklasB The link to pastie is not working. Plz give me sm code sample on how may I implement code.interact(...) Method... Ur method is very tempting

Comment: @earthdan The pastie is working fine for me, not sure what you mean. Here's the same code as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/niklasb/1c1b60e6c2c712e25a1b

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload :

> If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import
>   ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the
>   objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the
>   from statement, another is to use import and qualified names
>   (module.*name*) instead.

So, you should do something like:

```
from myapp import *
....
import myapp
reload(myapp)
from myapp import *
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I reload when using `from myapp import *`?

You can't. This is one of the reasons why using `from X import *` is a bad idea.

Comment: It's not a bad idea when debugging. It saves typing.

Answer (score 3):

With `from myapp import *`, you don't have a reference to your module in a variable name, so you can't use a variable name to refer to the module.

Of course, there's nothing preventing you from importing it again to get the reference to the module in a name you can use. Since it's already been imported once, it won't actually be imported again:

```
import myapp
reload(myapp)
```

You can also get the reference directly from `sys.modules`.

```
import sys
reload(sys.modules["myapp]")
```

Comment: Importing and reloading the module won't actually re-bind any names that were bound with `from foo import *`. This may or many not make the reload useless.

Comment: The reason I use *reload()* is because I change the source code of the module and test it and the reason I use *from myapp import* is because it saves me typing.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Wooble's comment, using "from foo import *" brings everything from foo into the current namespace.  This can lead to name collisions (where you unintentionally assign a new value to a name already in use) and can also make it harder to tell where something came from.  While a few libraries are often used this way, it generally causes more problems than it is worth.

Also, since it has been brought into the current namespace it cannot simply be reloaded.  It is generally better to keep it in a separate namespace (perhaps with a shorter convenience alias like just m).  This allows you to reload (which is useful for testing, but rarely a good idea outside of testing) and helps keept he namespace pure.